# Can't get certificate message credentials to work in my WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, authentication, ssl

I made a console application that hosts a WCF service. I am now trying to modify it. Here is what currently works...

**Program.cs**:

```
namespace FileRetrievalPoC
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var address = "https://localhost:8000/FileRetrievalPoC";
            Console.WriteLine("Starting a service at {0}...", address);
            FileRetrievalService.Start(address, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.TrustedPeople, "b7ba8f6e4c33ba55053f2e85898b383e40bf8ac9");
            Console.WriteLine("Service started.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to create a new proxy client and call the Get method.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press Escape to end the application.");
            while (true)
            {
                var key = Console.ReadKey();
                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    var proxy = FileRetrievalService.Connect(address, "localhost", "username", "password");
                    Console.WriteLine("Read the following from the server: {0}", proxy.Get(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Document.txt"));
                    FileRetrievalService.CloseClients();
                }
                else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                    break;
            }
            FileRetrievalService.CloseServer();
        }
    }
}
```

**FileRetrievalService.cs**:

```
class FileRetrievalService : IFileRetrieval
{

    private static BasicHttpsBinding _binding = new BasicHttpsBinding()
    {
        HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.Exact,
        Security = new BasicHttpsSecurity()
        {
            Message = new BasicHttpMessageSecurity()
            {
                AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256Sha256Rsa15,
                ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName
            },
            Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential,
            Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity()
            {
                ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows,
            }
        }
    };
    private static ChannelFactory<IFileRetrieval> _channelFactory;
    private static ServiceHost _host;

    public static void Start(string address, StoreLocation location, StoreName name, string thumbprint)
    {
        _host = new ServiceHost(typeof(FileRetrievalService));
        _host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(location, name, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint);
        _host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IFileRetrieval), _binding, address);
        _host.Open();
    }

    public static void CloseClients()
    {
        if (_channelFactory != null)
            _channelFactory.Close();
        _channelFactory = null;
    }

    public static void CloseServer()
    {
        if (_host != null)
            _host.Close();
        _host = null;
    }

    public static void CloseServerAndClients()
    {
        CloseServer();
        CloseClients();
    }

    public static IFileRetrieval Connect(string address, string domain, string username, string password)
    {
        if (_channelFactory == null)
        {
            _channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IFileRetrieval>(_binding, address);
            _channelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = domain + '\\' + username;
            _channelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;
            _channelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
        }
        return _channelFactory.CreateChannel();
    }

    public string Get(string path)
    {
        return File.ReadAllText(path);
    }

    public void Set(string path, string contents)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(path, contents);
    }
}
```

**IFileRetrieval.cs**:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFileRetrieval
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Get(string path);
    [OperationContract]
    void Set(string path, string contents);
}
```

All the above code works, because:

1. Server-side has `ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName` on the binding.
2. Client-side sets the username credentials on the `_channelFactory.Credentials.UserName` object.

I want to add more security, and have the client-side also provide an SSL certificate when connecting to the server. In order to try to do this, I have made the following replacements in the code for points 1 and 2 with the following logic:

1. I am trying to use `ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate` on the binding instead of `ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName`.
2. In the `Connect` method, I am now setting the client's certificate (`_channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(location, name, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint);`) and modified the method to take the appropriate certificate information (`StoreLocation location, StoreName name, string thumbprint`) passing in exactly the same parameters to reference, from the client-side, the same certificate that is presented from the server-side. I have removed the previous logic that sets the `_channelFactory.Credentials.UserName` object.

This did not work, and I get the following exception:

> An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other
>   party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.

Its inner exception says:

> An error occurred when verifying security for the message.

Where does one go from here? I am not using IIS, so how can I trace this error further? I am at a bit of a loss. I was hoping someone could explain what might be wrong, and what I can do to fix the error or debug it further.

**Edit**: I figured out a way to debug it further, but its not much more helpful than I thought it would be. Inside of my `App.config`, I added the following tracing:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="listener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData= "C:\Users\YourAccountUsername\Desktop\WCFTraces.svclog" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="listener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData= "C:\Users\YourAccountUsername\Desktop\WCFTraces.svclog" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Now inside of `WCFTraces.svclog`, I see a bunch of exceptions from the server side as well. The first one being:

> Security processor was unable to find a security header in the
>   message. This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or
>   because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating parties.
>   This can occur if the service is configured for security and the
>   client is not using security.

I'm not sure why the message does not have a security header, considering I've specified the client certificate. What is the client code missing?

**Edit**: Ah, I also see this error:

> The key size requirements for the 'Basic256Sha256Rsa15' algorithm
>   suite are not met by the
>   'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken' token which has key
>   size of '8192'.

Its under received bytes. My certificate has an 8192-byte private and public key, but this must not be a good match for my selected `AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256Sha256Rsa15`. Does anyone know what I should do here to allow this certificate? I can try using a 256 bit key for this...or is the problem that the signature algorithm is 512 bits on my certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, at last. The errors mislead me down a dark path, but now I got it.

**The Problem**

It seems an unwritten rule. When you specify `Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential` to tell it to use both message and transport credentials, and you then use a certificate for your message credentials,

```
Message = new BasicHttpMessageSecurity()
{
    AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256Sha256Rsa15,
    ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate
}
```

**You cannot use a certificate for your message credentials if it has over 4096 bits for its keys.**

**The Solution**

I made a new self-signed certificate with a 4096-bit RSA keypair, using SHA 512 as the signature algorithm.