# My web application is rejecting Windows authentication for a local Windows account

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, server, webrequest

My issue is that my service only lets my own Windows account connect to it, but I would like to allow connections from any valid Windows domain accounts. My service is hosted in IIS Express. When I browse to `https://localhost:44300/FileRetrievalService.svc/get` in Google Chrome, I see my `[WebGet]` method is called just fine. When I try to create a web request to it, it also works, as long as I specify my own Windows user account:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers.Add("Path", filePath);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "localhost");
return request.GetResponse();
```

When I try specifying a different local Windows account on my machine to authenticate a user against my service by changing `"username"` and `"password"` in the above code to another account which I know for sure exists on my machine, I get the following error:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized.

I have the following in my service's `Web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithTransportSecurity">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="FileRetrievalPoCV3.FileRetrievalService">
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithTransportSecurity" contract="FileRetrievalPoCV3.IFileRetrieval" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What is the cause of this issue?

Comment: I'm going to guess your account has admin priveleges, and the other account does not.  If that's the case, you need to explicitly give permissions to your project folder (i.e. using Windows Explorer) or assign that user to a group that already has permission.

Comment: @Keith You're correct, my project folder did not have permissions for my non-administrative user. I added permissions for the `Users` group which that account is a part of and it let the connection take place. However, I find this a bit odd, because it worked out of the box when I made a programmatic service that basically did the same thing (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326727/cant-get-certificate-message-credentials-to-work-in-my-wcf-service). The only difference is that I am now hosting in IIS Express. Why could that be? Because of IIS?

Comment: @Keith Oh, I see why now. As an IIS Express, and hostable IIS site, the service file needs to actually be served to the user, which means IIS Express and IIS use reflection to try and get the file using that user's privileges. I get it now.

Comment: By the way, if anyone is interested, all I needed was read permissions for that user account to my service .svc file within the bin folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess your account has admin priveleges, and the other account does not. If that's the case, you need to explicitly give permissions to your project folder (i.e. using Windows Explorer) or assign that user to a group that already has permission.

Comment: Just a note, it only needs read permissions on the service (*.svc) file for the corresponding user.